# Perl: Join/Splits- uninitialized variable

Tags: perl

I am trying to add quotation marks to the start and finish of a line which has being read in from a CSV file, then split and added into an array

```
a,b,c<br /> x,y,z<br />
```

and resulting in:

```
"a,b,c"

"x,y,z"
```

My data looks like My data looks like:

```
a,b,c<br /> x,y,z<br />
```

The code I am using is:

```
my @lines = join("\"", split (qr{<br\s?/>})), $line;
```

Which I would assume would work but I keep getting:

```
"Use of uninitialized value $_"
```

I am trying to find out how to solve this, I am assume that It (for someone) would be something simple that I am missing.

Extra Information

I know if I wanted to add quotation marks to the start and very finish I would uses:

```
push (@lines, "\"");
    unshift (@lines, "\"");

    my $newStr = join $/, @lines;
    print $newStr;
```

The full code is:

```
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;
use Data::Dumper;

use constant debug => 0;
use Text::CSV;

print "Running CSV editor......\n";

#my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => ',' });

my $file = $ARGV[0] or die "Need to get CSV file on the command line\n";

my $fileextension = substr($file, -4);

#If the file is a CSV file then read in the file.
if ($fileextension =~ m/csv/i) { 

  print "Reading and formating: $ARGV[0] \n";

  open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

  my @fields;

  while (my $line = <$data>) {   
    #Clears the white space at the end of the line.
    chomp $line;

    #Splits the line up and removes the <br />.
    my @lines = join("\"", split (qr{<br\s?/>})), $line;    

    #Removes the control character.   
    shift (@lines); 
    print "\n";
    #print $_, $/ for @lines;
  }         
  print "\n Finished reading and formating: $ARGV[0] \n";
}
else { 
  print "Error: File is not a CSV file\n"
}
```

Comment: yeah, that is. `split` take as default parameter `$_`. you need to specify correct line, which you want to split by `split` function. I will do this in your case: `split /delimiter/, $splitThisLine`

Comment: Please can we see some *real* input data and the corresponding output you want? You haven't shown anything that contains `<br/>`.

I think you are confusing Perl with C, as you appear to think you can access the characters of a string through an array.

What is happening is that you are creating an array `@lines` with a single element equal to the return value of `join`.

You immediately remove this element with a call to `shift` with the comment *Removes the control character* so the array ends up empty

Comment: I have added an example of data, Surely shit(@lines) removes the first element in the array, which in my case is a control character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: Please **always** [`use strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) in all your programs.

---

One of the closing brackets is at the wrong place.

```
my @lines = join("\"", split (qr{<br\s?/>})), $line;
                                           ^-- The second arg of split goes here.
```

What you have done is, split the implicit `$_` at `<br/>` and then join the resulting list together with `$line` using `"` as the new delimiter.

This would look like:

```
$line = 'a<br/>b<br/>c';
# split...
# Result: a"b"c"a<br/>b<br/>c
```

Use this instead:

```
my @lines = join('"', split(qr{<br\s?/>}, $line));
```

In fact, you can leave out the brackets entirely. Perl will figure it out in this case. I also changed the quoting. If you 
use single quotes you do not need to escape the `"` sign.

```
my @lines = join '"', split qr{<br\s?/>}, $line;
```

Example:

```
my $line = 'a<br/>b<br/>c'; 
my @lines = join "\"", split qr{<br\s?/>}, $line;
print Dumper \@lines;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'a"b"c'
        ];
```

---

Also note that [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) takes a list and returns a single string, not an array.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if perhaps your data actually looks something like this

```
<br/>a,b,c<br/>x,y,z
```

in which case what you need is

```
my @lines = split m|<br\s*/>|, $line;
print qq("$_"\n) for grep /\S/, @lines;
```

but your information isn't consistent and I am only guessing here

Comment: My data looks like:a,b,c<br /> x,y,z<br />

Comment: +1 I was thinking the same thing. The whole `join '"'` part is very strange... but I ran out of time so I didn't follow it up in my answer.